# How to open Skype from a react-native app using Linking

Tags: react-native, skype, skypedeveloper

I want to be able to open Skype with a call setup with a specific username from my react-native app. I had planned to use linking to do this, For example:

```
onLaunchPress = () => {
  const { user } = this.props
  Linking.openURL('https://skype.com/' + user)
 .catch((error) => console.log(error))
})
```

This is not enough to add the correct query parameters, However I am unable to view the documentation on this as the page doesn't load here:

https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I am also concerned as to whether this is actually possible given what is posted here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_web-skype_messms-skype_instamessms/open-skype-for-web-from-a-react-native-app/eef6a4c6-6b05-4566-b9e1-2f13f9d05606

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuris), you should be able to open Skype with the following:

```
Linking.openUrl('skype:');
```

You should also be able to pass the User in too with:

```
Linking.openUrl(`skype:${user}`);
```